# How to prevent "Not responding" error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

We are a tracking software, we need to use Internet Explorer.

```
function track(url){
    window.setInterval(function (){
        $.getScript("http://" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + "." + url);
    },1000)
}

track("example.com/track.php");
```

However, after ~15 seconds, Internet Explorer stops it and says "Not responding" error. (in task manager). Which way should we follow to prevent this type of error ?

Comment: possibly, you have got a recursion by loading same script with this setInterval call, just increase period and add some console message to count how many times you code is called

Comment: Member for 5 years and you can't even format your code properly? Are you serious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This most likely happens because you give your function a 1 second interval between the script loadings, but it takes internet explorer more than 1 second to load the script and so it starts loading it again before it finished the first one, and that causes a high resource usage because it makes the loadings accumulate one on top of another before they even finish.

im not sure how your tracking works, but you could avoid that by using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` and call it again once its done, or set a higher interval (10 seconds maybe)

**the difference:**

`setTimeout()` - executes ONCE after the specified time

`setInterval()` - keeps executing forever with the specified interval time.

**EXAMPLES**

**-higher interval:**

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    $.getScript("http://" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + "." + url);
}, 10000)
```

**-use timeout instead of interval:**

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    $.getScript("http://" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + "." + url);
}, 1000)
```

Comment: That works like a charm! It also has decreased the cpu usage by 300%.
Thanks a lot!